Cable rigging for robot
Basically I want to a cable attached to a 6 axis robot which goes from axis 3-6 or whatever. I've done this fine with a Nurbs curve and hooks etc and it works great, follows the robots movement and everything. The only problem is the stretching, the real cable does not stretch but if I turn off stretching it comes away from the end of the robot.
Is it possible to have stretching off but maintain all hook points? So the slack goes else where like in the centre of the curve and not over the end?



If the cable can't stretch, but needs to stay connected on both ends... Then have you tried making the cable longer? Cause when you say "Have the slack go elsewhere, like in the center of the curve" that's like the dictionary definition of stretching.

Making it longer just pushes more cable out the end. This problem really isn't simple and ive tried so many options, and the 'slack going else where' is not stretching at all, its the slack produced when the length from a to b gets smaller. This happens when i move the robots IK solver target.
